# Go 'up' scope in meteor blaze?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

How can I use a variable in a scope up from the current scope in Blaze?

For example:

```
<template name="userLayoutEditCreate">
    {{#each findUser id}}
    <h3>I am a single user (edit/create)</h3>
    <h3>{{id}}</h3>
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <!-- Primary instruments multi-select -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="playerPrimaryInstrument">Primary instruments</label>
                <div class="controls text-left">
                    <select id="playerPrimaryInstrument" name="playerPrimaryInstrument">
                        {{#each instruments}}
                        <option value="{{name}}" {{#if equals primary_instrument name}} selected="selected" {{/if}}>{{name}}</option>
                        {{/each}}
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

The if statement does not run within the each block. But it does run outside of the each block (I have defined the helper).

The error I get looks like this.

```
Reactive HTML attributes must either have a constant name or consist of a single {{helper}} providing a dictionary of names and values.  A template tag of type BLOCKOPEN is not allowed here.
```

==== EDIT ====

Even using the '../' scope definition didn't work in this case. What DID work was putting the expression inside the value of the selected attribute. I'm not sure why that is, please let me know if you have any idea?

The solution:

```
{{#each instruments}}
    <option value="{{name}}" selected="{{#if equals name ../primary_instrument}} selected {{/if}}">{{name}}</option>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{{#if equals ../primary_instrument name}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Hi, no. that doesn't work. I'm trying on this code: {{#if equals 'hi' 'hi'}} selected="selected" {{/if}}

Comment: Thanks, the scope thing "../" did actually work. I've edited the question to show where I was having the problem